# Cannot list Home folder

Tags: 10.04, permissions, home-directory

All of a sudden I can't access my home folder. I am using ubuntu 10.04.

I can access the folders inside it ( Desktop, Videos etc ) but if I want to see inside the home itself ( either in Nautilus or with ls in terminal ) I get nothing ( in Nautilus it says loading in terminal and outputs nothing ).

I can access the folder as root.
I did a chown on the whole folder .. still nothing.
I get a warning that it can't change the owner for a folder (.gvfs). It seems I can't even delete as root.

Comment: Look at [this question](http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com/questions/2684/my-home-directory-just-goes-away-why); you may have the same problem. In any case, follow the investigative steps mentioned in that thread, starting by `/bin/ls -A ~` and `/bin/ls -lA ~` at a command prompt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey. assuming so, but you did `chown -R` to make sure you hit all the other files?

check permissions on whatever file you can't access (assuming you can see it at all?)

Are you just not able to view anything in the folder at all, or what?

`sudo ls -la /home/solomon/` and maybe you'll see what's up.

Comment: i did just that, and the problem was with one of the folders that could not be read properly. after i deleted it everything went back to normal. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It might be caused by a problematic symbolic link. I had a broken symbolic link in `~` pointing at a remote network directory. Removing it did help.

Other broken symbolic links in `~` pointing at `/media/<whatever>` are not causing any issues though.